# Accessing a non-static method from a static method issue

Tags: c#, wpf

I apologize for lacking information.

I have created a class in my solution called: myClass.cs
- myClass contains a static method with the following code:

```
public static void myFunction()
{
    MainWindow obj = new MainWindow();
    obj.someFunction();
}
```

MainWindow is the GUI window which contains textboxes, etc. 
The class: MainWindow.cs contains the following method which I'm trying to call from myClass.cs:

```
public void someFunction()
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Hello!");
        }
```

Short brief: "Hello!" doesn't show up.

Brief explenation:
Now here's the issue: When I debug it executes the line: "MainWindow obj = new MainWindow()", however, once it's done it just skips to the end of the function (curly brace).

Comment: Does the compiler optimize code ? You are not returning obj so unless someFunction has some side effect outside obj instance it could well be stripped away.

Comment: show more code.. this is a very broad question at best....

Comment: What is calling the static `myFunction`?

Comment: Could the constructor of MainWindow be throwing an exception?

Comment: @Erik, no it's not throwing an exception.

Comment: @ D Stanley it's a ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult ar)

Comment: The code as you show it will behave as expected. There's something else out there that isn't here. You over-simplified the question. Please show us that `ReceiveCallback` stuff and the other meaningfull part of the *real* code.

Answer (score 3):

Neither of your observations make sense - programs just do not "skip" lines without being told to*, and it's NOT obvious that it doesn't execute.

My guess is that you have an *existing* `MainWindow` instance and you're expecting that function to affect that instance.  If that's the case, then you need to get a reference to the instance you want to execute the function on; most easily by adding it as a parameter:

```
public static void myFunction(MainWindow obj) {
    obj.someFunction();
}
```

<sub>*With the exception of compiler optimizations, where the code can be removed without affecting the output.</sub>

Comment: I apologize for lacking information. - Wait pressed enter by mistake will edit this post